# Complex DTO and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
class PeopleDTO
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<AwardDTO> Awards { get; set; }
}


class AwardDTO
{
    int AwardID {get; set; }
    string AwardName {get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to use LINQ to filter my People Object for anyone who has an 'AwardID' equal to 5. I've tried the following but I'm not getting it:

```
List<PeopleDTO> people = GetPeople();
var test = (from p in people.Where(a => a.Awards.Where(a => a.AwardID == 5)) select p).ToList();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: on a slightly different note, your class is better named `PersonDTO` than people one.

Answer (score 2):

```
people.Where(p=>p.Awards.Any(a=>a.AwardId == 5)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just one small change:

```
List<PeopleDTO> people = GetPeople();
var test = (from p in people.Where(a => a.Awards.Any(a => a.AwardID == 5)) select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = people.Where(l => l.Awards.Any(a => a.AwardId == 5));
```

would do.. That's just the query part, you may want to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Where` returns the matching element *sequence* and thus the resulting type is wrong. Here is the fundamental issue:

```
// Wrong (type error)
from p in people
  .Where(
     // Results in type error as result of Where is Enumerable, not bool.
     // The lambda signature is People => Enumerable[Award] which is
     // incompatible with People => bool required for the outer Where.
     a => a.Awards.Where(a => a.AwardID == 5)
  )
select p

// Working - but NOT ideal as it forces materialization of the
// matching award count! However, types are correct.
from p in people
  .Where(
     // Now we get a lambda: People => bool
     a => a.Awards.Where(a => a.AwardID == 5).Count() > 0
  )
select p
```

The more ideal solution than `Where(f).Count() > 0` is `Any(f)`, as discussed in other answers. Besides being more clear, `Any` is also usually advantageous because it does not require that the sequence is materialized first - after all, every source element could have matched.

The actual result of a Where will be an `IEnumerable[X]` or `IQueryable[X]` depending upon the source on which it is applied against. The point is that Where alone results in an incompatible value and thus results in an incorrectly-typed lambda.